# Get links thru JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this situation:

```
 $.getJSON(url, args,
        function(data) {
            info("");
            $("#results").empty();
            if (! ('songs' in data.response)) {
                info("Can't find anything");
            } else {
                $("#all_results").show();
                var tbody = $("#all_results_body");
                tbody.empty();
                $.each(data.response.songs, function(i, song) {
                    var row = $("<tr>");
                    var artist = song.artist_name;
                    //var artist = make_link(song.artist_name, 
                            //'http://static.echonest.com/echotron/?id=' + song.artist_id, 'other');
                    var tid = song.tracks[0].foreign_id.replace('-WW', '');
                    var tid = tid.replace('-US', '');
                    var title = make_link(song.title, tid);

                    /*var nacousticness = Math.round(song.audio_summary.acousticness * 10000) / 10000;*/

                    row.append( $("<td style='width:5%;'>").text(i + 1) );
                    row.append( $("<td style='width:40%;'>").append(artist));
                    row.append( $("<td style='width:55%;'>").append(title) );
                    
                    /*row.append( $("<td>").text(nacousticness));*/
                     tbody.append(row);
                    console.log(song.artist_id, song.id, song.audio_summary.acousticness, 
                        song.artist_name, song.title);
                     document.write(tid + "&nbsp;");
                        
                        
                        
                });
            }
        },
```

The document.write give the result and its like::

> spotify:track:4ISIMO6EMPq9auijVz0MoB spotify:track:5yJo1wqMVw6XWZaGRl9kQC  spotify:track:32uqV4nV8P0CiRDaVrEbcY spotify:track:3YFw3zTOzjCs7PL6ebNhho
> spotify:track:1kQEgJ8C2wSrGBLa5YCKpe spotify:track:3wFqyQrlY7NfEriHCGdbyy spotify:track:0AcyyjJh01tIrwBn538Bk1 spotify:track:6dQJI4hFolhMnZhSHxkuGc spotify:track:4r13PlX7hKjNxdyq5ukR5A spotify:track:1Oenqmtbzt331Pgv0ODfS2 spotify:track:7nFlzPTW9WGNJ2y9t3Tfvw spotify:track:3zIauDOxaYXR404SPlX9bv spotify:track:1uAwfDonpvw6Z4OsITZzzA spotify:track:3ssX20QT5c3nA9wk78V1LQ spotify:track:7vB7thPuSBLqG1LnTq8Yf7 spotify:track:3dmnVNKCxtohL1FJsM7xWr spotify:track:4oQgsytVrNH5dOdiLRVKCx spotify:track:6VD2YPeb1P3BCP5q0lZHrs spotify:track:3NOUuHRQHMcfqht2OTgQqP spotify:track:3ia3dJETSOllPsv3LJkE35

I want to save these value to a button or to a textarea.

Comment: What is make_link, where's the button, and what's in the title row?  You can select anchor elements in your header with $(tableSelector).find("th a") (and from there, select the href attribute to get the link).  It's difficult to help you without any more information/code.

Comment: please provide sample data (as they are retrieved from your API), so we can test your code.

Comment: Does your page have a `textarea` already? If so and let's say it has `id="spotifytracks"` you can just do `$('#spotifytracks').val($('#spotifytracks').val()+'&nbsp'+tid);` in stead of `document.write`;